# Movable and re-sizable div, child divs re-sizing with it?

Tags: jquery, css, html, resizable

Ok so I have literally made a "My Computer "window purely from CSS3. I'm gonna finish it, and what I'd like to be able to do is move it about and make the window re-sizable.

Some child classes only want to resize in width, and some want to re-size in width AND height. That seems like quite a task, and I'm actually more concerned about the moving of the div. I've given it a go a few times and I just an't get it to work!

Can someone possibly help me? Maybe a JFiddle of it working? I appreciate it guys!

EDIT: Here's the site, SORRY!:

http://projects.beauaugust.co.uk/windows98/

View source, it's all in there!

Comment: literally made a window? what kind of window - literally a real window? Why don't you put what you have got on jsFiddle so people can easily start from that point.

Comment: here you go! :) http://jsfiddle.net/BeauAugust/Sc2Qm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/? I imagine that you could get the functionality you desire between those two and some custom code.

I just looked at your code on jfiddle and put this:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".window" ).draggable().resizable();
});
```

which worked great to make it draggable. It resized to a degree, too. To make the resize work better, it would be best if you gave relative sizes to the child elements of window (like 100%) instead of pixel sizes.

I hope that helps. If so, please mark as answer.

Comment: I've tried draggable, and it wouldn't work. That's why I was hoping for a demo of it working on my own code. Sorry!

Comment: I tried that in JsFiddle and it worked perfectly as well. Weird. I don't know what the problem was previously. With the resizable problem, do you know how I can get the children divs to resize along with it?

Comment: Just make all the height and width values relative. instead of     height: 20px; width: 590px; try height: 100%; width: 10%;

Comment: Ok well width works, I'll attempt to fix it height-wise. You're a star, thanks!

Comment: Good good...it's well on it's way. Is there a way to make the div SMALLER? I can only make it bigger haha. It's well on it's way though - take a look!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [Interface Elements with JQuery](http://interface.eyecon.ro/)

Here are a list of [demos](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/?page=demos).

In particular you may want to look at this [one](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/drag.html)

Other stuff from that the Interface plugin can help you as well like this [one](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/scrollbar.html) (when do implement scroll)

But have a play with the interface plugin for JQuery. It is very useful in my opinion.

Comment: That looks good. Especially that "drag by handle". I'll give that a smash and see if I can mash some magic together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm right there with Robert.  I'm not sure that CSS has the ability to make things that dynamic.  In which case the solution is Javascript or as proposed (and much more simple) jquery.

I could be mistaken, but I think in order for javascript (possibly jquery as well) to pinpoint exactly what you want to be able to do anything to, you need to use the 'id' attribute.

```
<div class="window" id="window_main">
```

Then when you use the jquery functions, you can apply the drag quality to "window_main".

Hope that helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Are you kidding me?! CRAP! I've been doing everything class-based. I'll try that out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: That failed miserably :( Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Sc2Qm/1/

Currently resizable will only resize `.window` due to the way you have your html and CSS layed out.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried changing it to 100% width like I had it previously, but it makes things overlap. I need to sort that problem out.

Comment: Problem solved, I just set it the 99% and it worked like a charm. THANKS!